# What is wrong with this simple PHP/SQL survey?

Tags: php, mysql

so I am making a simple PHP/SQL/HTML survey, and it is not submitting to the database for some reason... No errors or syntax errors, the page displays fine, it just doesn't submit and insert it into phpmyadmin's "Survey" table

the database and table names are correct, I double checked the SQL by inserting the rows using the 'Insert' button in phpmyadmin and it worked fine, gave me the same SQL so I figure it must be with my PHP

Thanks, here is my code

```
<?php
include "Header.php";

if (!$User)
{
header("Location: index.php"); exit();
}

echo"
<center><br /><br /><br /><h1>Social-Limiteds Survey</h1><br /><h3>Please take a moment         to fill out this survey to help us improve the site</h3><br /><br />
In your opinion, who is the most helpful staff member?</font><br /><br /><form     action='' method='post'><textarea name='Quest1' rows='2' cols='20'></textarea><br />
In your opinion, who is the best item creator who is currently NOT a staff member?    </font><br /><br /><form action='' method='post'><textarea name='Quest2' rows='2'     cols='20'></textarea><br />
In your opinion, who is the best Forumer?</font><br /><br /><form action=''     method='post'><textarea name='Quest3' rows='2' cols='20'></textarea><br />
In your opinion, who is the best Artist?</font><br /><br /><form action=''     method='post'><textarea name='Quest4' rows='2' cols='20'></textarea><br />
Is Braixen cute? (Yes/No) </font><br /><br /><form action='' method='post'><textarea     name='Quest5' rows='2' cols='20'></textarea><br />
<input type='submit' name='submit' value='Send'></form></center>";


$Ques1 = mysql_real_escape_string(strip_tags($_POST['Quest1']));
$Ques2 = mysql_real_escape_string(strip_tags($_POST['Quest2']));
$Ques3 = mysql_real_escape_string(strip_tags($_POST['Quest3']));
$Ques4 = mysql_real_escape_string(strip_tags($_POST['Quest4']));
$Ques5 = mysql_real_escape_string(strip_tags($_POST['Quest5']));

if ($Submit) {

mysql_query("INSERT INTO `socialli_main`.`Survey` (`Question1`, `Question2`,     `Question3`, `Question4`, `Question5`, `Username`, `ID`) VALUES ('$Ques1', '$Ques2',     '$Ques3', '$Ques4', '$Ques5', '$myU->Username', NULL);");

header("Location: index.php"); exit();
}

include "Footer.php";
```

Comment: Do you have the same issue when using `"'.$Ques1.'"` for all variables instead? (Appending to string). Secondly, are you sure `$Submit == true`?

Comment: I have not tried that, would it work?

Comment: Also, you might want to enable error reporting like so: `ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
error_reporting(E_ALL);`

Comment: *would it work?* don't ask that TRY IT

Comment: Can we assume that the included Header.php takes care of the database connection?

Comment: mysql_* = bad, and your html leaves a lot to be desired.

Comment: mysql_ is depricated indeed. But, it achieves the same as PDO, although you have to make sure you are doing it the right way.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing every argument to a structre like this: `"'.$Ques1.'"`

Secondly, are you sure `$Submit == true`?

You might want to enable error debugging so you can see all warnings and errors, that might show you the solution:

```
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: What about the database connection, are you sure the connection was made properly? And I assume the Header.php file handles the Database connection? Try to look in the page source in your web browser to check if there are any PHP errors/warnings in the source, at places you can't see them in your browser itself. This is usually on the end of the page source.

Comment: Yes, Header.php handles it

Comment: Have you checked your page source for errors, that might solve the issue.